# tomcat 7 conf/web.xml custom error page not picked up by webapps

Tags: java, tomcat, centos

I am setting up a custom 404 page in tomcat 7(CentOS 5).

```
<error-page> 
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error/404.html</location>
</error-page>
```

The problem now is

```
localhost:8080/badlink displays 404.html
```

but when using with webapps/sample

```
localhost:8080/sample/badlink displays a blank page
```

The logs for /sample/badlink shows

```
 FINE: Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=404, location=/error/404.html]
```

I think tomcat picks up the custom 404 page but it doesn't serve it to the browser.
Is it because the error/404.html is placed in the webapps/ROOT so other webapps dont have access it
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple problem, the error/404.html should be added each webapp installed. So redundant copies of  the files is used instead of single global file i.e

```
/usr/tomcat/webapps/sample/error/404.html
/usr/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/error/404.html
..
```

I couldnt find any alternative.

Comment: Hi, don't you know any alternatives so far?